# How do I fix this code? (Multi-Dimensional)

Tags: python-3.x

Imagine there is a chessboard. I want my function to return True if no 2 Queens (indicated by 1 in the code below) are located diagonally.

```
chess = [[1, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 1, 0],
         [0, 1, 0, 0],
         [0, 0, 1, 0]]


def diagonal_check(chess):
    v = []
    z = []
    for y in range(len(chess)):
        v.append(map(lambda x: x[len(chess) - y - 1], chess[y]))
    for t in range(len(chess)):
        z.append(map(lambda x: x[t], chess[t]))

    if len(list(filter(lambda x: x == [1], v))) > 1 or len(list(filter(lambda x: x == [1], z))) > 1:
        return False
    else:
        return True

print(diagonal_check(chess))
```

For some reason, my code returns me True all the time despite the chess above showing 2 of '1's diagonally. Can anybody help me with this? There might be better answers to solving this question overall, but I want to know how I can fix this particular code.

On closer look, I realise something is wrong with the x[], chess[y] portion. But I am not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution would be to not use map in this case, because its not helping.

```
def diagonal_check(chess):
    v = []
    z = []
    for y in range(len(chess)):
        v.append(chess[y][len(chess) - y - 1])
    for t in range(len(chess)):
        z.append(chess[t][t])

    if len(list(filter(lambda x: x == 1, v))) > 1 or len(list(filter(lambda x: x == 1, z))) > 1:
        return(False)
    else:
        return(True)
```

`map` would return an iterator and will not evaluate it right away. So you would either need to call next on each `map` object or cast it explicitly to a list.